# Sp Online and PnP and remote provisioning : create folders in custom Document Library

Tags: folder, xml, list-template, pnp, remote-provisioning

Hello fellow sharepointers !

I need your help on my provisioning template.

I am creating a new Document library which is bound to a custom content Type.
I want to add a whole architecture of folders and unfortunately can't make it work, i don't know why.

**What i have :**

my XML Template :
GED_SiteLibrariesCreation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<pnp:Provisioning xmlns:pnp="http://schemas.dev.office.com/PnP/2015/12/ProvisioningSchema">
  <pnp:Preferences></pnp:Preferences>
  <pnp:Templates>
    <pnp:ProvisioningTemplate ID="GED_SiteLibrariesCreation">
      <pnp:Lists>
          <pnp:ListInstance Title="Documents projet"
                          Description="Documents partagées entre les acteurs du projet (ASI et client)"
                          TemplateType="101"
                          Url="documentprojet"
                          EnableVersioning="true"
                          EnableMinorVersions="true"
                          MinorVersionLimit="20"
                          MaxVersionLimit="100"
                          DraftVersionVisibility="0"
                          ContentTypesEnabled="true"
                          RemoveExistingContentTypes="true"
                          EnableFolderCreation="true">
            <pnp:ContentTypeBindings>
              <pnp:ContentTypeBinding ContentTypeID="0x010100BBD2E6E36069334ABFD4717B8C2FA4D9" Default="true" />
              <pnp:ContentTypeBinding ContentTypeID="0x010100BBD2E6E36069334ABFD4717B8C2FA4D901"/>
              <pnp:ContentTypeBinding ContentTypeID="0x010100BBD2E6E36069334ABFD4717B8C2FA4D902"/>
            </pnp:ContentTypeBindings>
            <pnp:FieldDefaults>
              <pnp:FieldDefault FieldName="EtatValidation">Brouillon</pnp:FieldDefault>
              <pnp:FieldDefault FieldName="EtatValidationCR">A valider</pnp:FieldDefault>
            </pnp:FieldDefaults>

            <pnp:Folders>
              <pnp:Folder Name="01.TEST">
                  <pnp:Folder Name="0102. TEST"></pnp:Folder>
              </pnp:Folder>

            </pnp:Folders>
        </pnp:ListInstance>
 </pnp:Lists>
      
     
    </pnp:ProvisioningTemplate>
  </pnp:Templates>
</pnp:Provisioning>
```

**What do i get :**

My list is created or updated, but no folder are created.
I have absolutely no error nor output saying something went wrong.

I've followed letter to letter the examples given in the [provisioning schema](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-Provisioning-Schema/blob/master/ProvisioningSchema-2015-12.md#folders) on GitHub

Please, could you give me other examples or a clue on what could go wrong ?

Thanks a lot.

Have a nice day.

Comment: `<pnp:Folder Name="0102. TEST"></pnp:Folder>` instead of this, try it as 
`<pnp:Folder Name="0102. TEST"/>`

Comment: Hello @GautamSheth, thanks for your reply. I've tested as you said and it is still not working... Thanks for your time anyway, i hope it could help someone else ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried your template and everything works fine for me - folders are created (I deleted `ContentTypeBindings` since this content types don't exist in my environment).

I can recommend the following:

1. Make sure you are using latest version of PnP from nuget (I'm using `SharePointPnPCoreOnline.2.9.1611.0`)
2. If `#1` didn't help, try to remove all `ContentTypeBindings` like I did (may be that's an issue?)

**UPD**
So finally, thanks to @Gaelle comment, I was able to reproduce this behavior.
I found that there is a bug in PnP - [here is the link](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Sites-Core/issues/810) to corresponding issue reported October, 20.
Following code will not work for you:

```cs
var ctx = new ClientContext("https://sp.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/");
var subweb = ctx.Site.OpenWeb("tests");
ctx.Load(subweb);
ctx.ExecuteQueryRetry();
.....
subweb.ApplyProvisioningTemplate(template);
```

Besides this one works:

```cs
var ctx = new ClientContext("https://sp.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/tests");
ctx.Load(ctx.Web);
ctx.ExecuteQueryRetry();
....
ctx.Web.ApplyProvisioningTemplate(template);
```

And this is what is the issue about: in the first sample I'm using `OpenWeb` method and it doesn't work, for second sample I created client context using sub site url and it does work.

For now I think this is the only working workaround for you - construct new client context (don't forget about disposing) for subsite.

Comment: Hello @Kai, thanks for your comment. Normally my version of SharepointPnpCoreOnline is the good one. But because we are working on Azure, i will check if the packages are good on it.
Removing ContentTypeBindings did not work, and it won't be a real solution but only a workaround since we really need custom ContentType to be bound in our Doc Libraries...
i'll give a feedback later.

Comment: Hello @Kai I have a request for you : did you test my xml template on a ROOT site or on a WEB site ? (this could really be important).
Because we are creating and provisioning this library into a subsite (or website) under or site collection...
Thanks a lot for your feedback !

Comment: @Gaelle: now I see... please take a look at my update

Comment: THANKS A LOT ! Effectively, rebuilding client context with subweb URL is the solution ! We managed it. And well, i think maybe it is a better practice to reload the right context